# Scala case class "explicitly exposing the state"

Tags: scala, akka, immutability, case-class

While reading [akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#creating-actors) right under messages and immutability section, It mentions about "explicitly exposing the state" inside case class. So my questions are;

What is meant by saying "explicitly exposing the state" for case class?

In order to achieve immutability, isn't it enough to write "case" for a class?
Or I should be careful about its usage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is meant by saying "explicitly exposing the state" for case class?

The actor below represents its state with a mutable `Set[Int]`, which is initialized with the values `1`, `2`, and `3`:

```
case class State(s: mutable.Set[Int])

case class Add(num: Int)
case class Remove(num: Int)

class MyActor extends Actor {
  val state = mutable.Set(1, 2, 3)

  def receive = {
    case GetState =>
      sender ! State(state)
    case Add(i) =>
      state += i
    case Remove(i) =>
      state -= i
  }
}
```

When this actor receives a `GetState` message, it wraps its state in the `State` case class and sends that to the sender. Even though the `State` case class is immutable, its parameter `s` is a mutable `Set`. Therefore, when `MyActor` creates a `State` instance with its state and sends that as a message to the sender of the `GetState` message, `MyActor`'s state becomes modifiable outside of the boundaries of `MyActor` itself. To make this concrete, let's say `AnotherActor` sends a `GetState` message to `MyActor`, at which point `MyActor` sends its state to `AnotherActor`. Here is the latter actor:

```
class AnotherActor extends Actor {
  def receive =>
    case State(state) =>
      // MyActor's state is exposed here
      state -= 2
}
```

`AnotherActor` modifies `MyActor`'s state by removing `2` from it, even though that state is delivered inside a case class.

To mitigate this sort of leak, restrict mutability to the actor itself. In this example, instead of having a `val state = mutable.Set(1, 2, 3)`, define a `var state = immutable.Set(1, 2, 3)`:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  var state = immutable.Set(1, 2, 3)

  def receive = {
    case GetState =>
      sender ! state
    case Add(i) =>
      state = state + i
    case Remove(i) =>
      state = state - i
  }
}
```

Here, `MyActor` can safely send its state as a message because it's an immutable `Set` (we could wrap the `Set` inside a case class, but that's not essential in this case).

> In order to achieve immutability, isn't it enough to write "case" for a class?

No. When using a case class for actor messaging, ensure that all of the class's parameters are themselves immutable.

> Or I should be careful about its usage?

Yes.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it refers to doing something like

```
case class Broken(m: mutable.Map[String, String])
```

`Broken` is superficially immutable, because none of its fields can be directly set to anything, but it can still be altered by updating `m`, which will cause the behavior of the containing `Broken` to change (`hashCode`, `equals`, etc.), thereby breaking anything that relies on those being consistent. `m` corresponds to `Broken`'s internal (mutable) state, and exposing it allows `Broken` to be mutated, too.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're referring to this particular quote:

> Scala case classes which are immutable (if you don’t explicitly expose
>   the state)

In their simplest form, a case class constructor's parameters will be mapped to 'val' fields and hence their reference will be immutable. However if the field itself is mutable (e.g. referencing a mutable collection or object) *and* you expose that (via an accessor method, say), then the class will become mutable (since you've exposed a mutable field). Not that you can still change the state internally, however, if you so wish.