# How to extend the akka receive method in my current design

Tags: scala, akka

I have a actor like this:

```
class MyActor[T] extends Actor {
   def receive = {
      case Option1(t: T) =>
        doWork(t) onComplete .....
      case Option2 =>

   }

   def doWork(T): Future[T]{
   }
}
```

Then I have an actor that inherits from the above:

```
class OtherActor extends MyActor {
  val m = mutable.Map.empty[Int, User]
  override def doWork(..) = {
      //
  }
}
```

**Now in my `OtherActor` actor I want to add some methods to the receive method, how can I do this?**

Comment: Either dispatch from the original `receive`, or use `context.become`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the additional behavior in a `Receive` block inside `OuterActor` and chain that behavior to its parent's behavior with `orElse`:

```
class OtherActor extends MyActor {
  val m = mutable.Map.empty[Int, User]
  override def doWork(...) = ???

  val otherBehavior: Receive = {
    case ...
  }

  override def receive = otherBehavior.orElse(super.receive)
}
```

This is possible because `Receive` is just a type alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. More information on composing actor behaviors is found [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/actors.html#extending-actors-using-partialfunction-chaining).

As a side note, you should prefer `var m = immutable.Map.empty[Int, User]` instead of `val m = mutable.Map.empty[Int, User]` in order to help avoid exposing the actor's state, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244055/scala-case-class-explicitly-exposing-the-state/46244940#46244940).

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, see [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/27629)